# grails changelog preconditions not doing anything

Tags: grails, changelog, preconditions

I am trying to make changes to the database using the changelog.  Since I cannot guarantee that the values currently exist for the specific code, but could exist, I need to be able to check for them in order to either do an insert or an update.

Here is what I have been testing, which doesn't appear to do anything.  Any words of advice are welcome.

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author:'kmert', id:'tubecap-insert-update-1') {
        preConditions(onFail="WARN",onFailMessage:"Tube cap does not exist,skipping because it cannot be updated."){
            sqlCheck(expectedResult='1', 'SELECT * FROM [ltc2_tube_cap] WHERE code=11')
        }
        grailsChange {
            change {
                sql.execute("""
                    UPDATE [ltc2_tube_cap]
                    SET [name] = 'White'
                    WHERE [code] = 11;
                """)
            }
            rollback {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I got the changelog script running, but I am now getting this error.  I found the code from an online source.  I cannot find a lot of documentation on preconditions...

| Starting dbm-update for database hapi_app_user @ jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=LabTraffic;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
problem parsing TubeCapUpdate.groovy: No signature of method: grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.sqlCheck() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [1, SELECT * FROM ltc2_tube_cap WHERE code=11] (re-run with --verbose to see the stacktrace)
problem parsing changelog.groovy: No signature of method: grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.sqlCheck() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [1, SELECT * FROM ltc2_tube_cap WHERE code=11] (re-run with --verbose to see the stacktrace)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.sqlCheck() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [1, SELECT * FROM ltc2_tube_cap WHERE code=11]
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.invokeMethod(DslBuilder.groovy:117)
    at Script1$_run_closure1_closure2_closure3.doCall(Script1.groovy:13)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.invokeMethod(DslBuilder.groovy:117)
    at Script1$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(Script1.groovy:12)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.invokeMethod(DslBuilder.groovy:117)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:11)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GrailsChangeLogParser.parse(GrailsChangeLogParser.groovy:84)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.handleIncludedChangeLog(DslBuilder.groovy:747)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.createNode(DslBuilder.groovy:139)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.createNode(DslBuilder.groovy:590)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.DslBuilder.invokeMethod(DslBuilder.groovy:117)
    at Script1$_run_closure1.doCall(Script1.groovy:6)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.GrailsChangeLogParser.parse(GrailsChangeLogParser.groovy:84)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:107)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate:26)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2_closure11.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:59)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at _DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_DatabaseMigrationCommon_groovy:51)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmUpdate:25)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect for the sqlCheck preCondition.

```
 sqlCheck(expectedResult:'1', 'SELECT * FROM [ltc2_tube_cap] WHERE code=11')
```

Notice in your code the first argument is an assignment statement `expectedResult=1` and it should be a map entry `expectedResult:1`.

I found the answer buried on this Jira page. https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION-40 which ironically is about adding lots of examples to the DB migration DSL to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following

```
grails dbm-gorm-diff add-your-file-forupdate.groovy -add
```

then inside your-file-forupdate.groovy is expected to see

```
databaseChangeLog = {
    changeSet(author:'kmert', id:'tubecap-insert-update-1') {
 .
 .
 .
    }
}
```

Then ,the Big deal is either you have included this as migration script file to be executed as follow:

just manually add a line like the following to the end of grails-**app/migrations/changelog.groovy:**

> include file: 'your-file-forupdate.groovy'

The changelog.groovy is always run from beginning to end, so make sure that you always add newly created migrations to the end.

Cheers! for more info see [this](http://wpgreenway.com/posts/grails-db-migration-tutorial/)

Comment: The file has been added to my changelog.groovy already.  I finally figured out that the reason it wasn't running at all was apparently another migration script was dying.  Now, that it is running my dilemma has changed.